# Symfony2 forwards when re-submit the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

When I send form with data on the server at the second time it redirects me on route which handle request from client.

What I mean

I have the controller method which accept request from client as AJAX and validate data

```
public function addCommentAction(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);
        $post->setCreated(new \DateTime('now'));
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->submit($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($post);
                $em->flush();
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Comment has been sent on moderation. Wait 1 minute before send another comment.');
            }
        }
        return $this->render('GuestbookBundle:Post:postForm.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

My ajax. Serialize form and after that send request to the server with data from form

```
$('.container .form-comment .send-comment').on('click', function(e) {
        var $from = $(this).closest('form');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $from.attr('action'),
            data: $from.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.form-comment').empty().append(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

When I click send button the second time it redirect me to the page mydomain.com/add, which handle request from form

```
add:
    path:     /add
    defaults: { _controller: GuestbookBundle:Post:addComment }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

How to fix this? Why after success send my form not clear?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that the on listener isn't registered the second time around

Comment: What you mean? Can you explain.

Comment: @MaximR what the expected result after form submit?

Comment: @MaximR on Error you return a form (including the button you register on I suspect). That form is not inside the DOM when you register the eventlistener in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are returning form again after submit, why do you need this?
As i see you are trying to add a comment, so after submit you can return message(e.g. - success) or any other data you need.

```
    public function addCommentAction(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);
        $result = ['status' => 'success',
                'comment' => 'Comment has been sent on moderation. Wait 1 minute before send another comment.' ];
        $post->setCreated(new \DateTime('now'));
        if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->submit($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($post);
                $em->flush();
//              $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Comment has been sent on moderation. Wait 1 minute before send another comment.');
                return new JsonResponse($result);
            } 
            $result['status'] = 'error';
            return new JsonResponse($result);
        }
        return $this->render('GuestbookBundle:Post:postForm.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

javascript:

```
$('.container .form-comment .send-comment').on('click', function(e) {
        var $from = $(this).closest('form');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $from.attr('action'),
            data: $from.serialize()

        }).done(function(data) {
                  //data will contains data.status && data.message
                  //you can add any data in your controller

            $('.form-comment').empty().append(data.messages);

        }).fail(function(data) {
            alert(data.messages);
        });
    });
```

also you are using deprecated syntax, 
better to use `$form->handleRequest($request);`, you can read about it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html)

Comment: @MaximR what you mean? symfony validation is ok

Comment: Yes. Its work, but how about validation, It's possible use symfony validation or I should manual to do that?

Comment: I mean how to use this validation  {{ form_errors(form.domain) }} or something like that and on each fields show what kind of mistake user to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found why they forward me on url after re-submit. On second time jquery din't work, because after response I receive new html and jquery can bind events on buttons. As a solution change JS code

```
$('.container .form-comment').on('submit', '.send-comment', function(e) {
});
```